# Why can I only Input a "1,5" but not a "1.5"

Tags: java, double

I coded a little program to calculate a tax, but I have a problem. The problem multiplies the number that I put in by 0.9975, but I can only put in a double number with a "," and not with a dot ".".

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Bitrex {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner Bitcoin = new Scanner (System.in);
        double num1;
        double num2=0.9975;
        double answer;

        System.out.println("Enter Expected Price: ");
        num1 = Bitcoin.nextDouble();
        answer = num1 * num2;
        System.out.println(answer);
    } // end of main
}
```

Comment: What is your `Locale`?

Comment: it is because your system is probably set to Germany where we use ',' instead of '.' to separate the decimals... and `Scanner` uses the default Locale. See the corresponding [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#localized-numbers)

Comment: Because in English '.' is *1000 separator. I.e.: 5.526,12 is equivalent to 5526.12 in European writing.

Comment: How can I change this?

Answer (score 1):

You probably are in Germany and `Scanner` uses the default `Locale`, that is, `,` is used as the decimal separator for parsing. See the [Javadoc of Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#localized-numbers).

You should set the `Locale` you want to use like in

```
...

Scanner Bitcoin = new Scanner (System.in);
Bitcoin.useLocale(Locale.US);  // or Locale.ROOT  or  new Locale("pt", "BR")

...
```

*(do not forget* `import java.util.Locale;`*)*

Eventually it is better to set the default Locale for the whole application using `Locale.setDefault(Locale.ROOT);`

Comment: WHICH symbol? maybe missing `import java.util.Locale;` ?